# M2: Setting delivery methods - exact configuration

Tags: magento2, shipping, configuration, shipping-methods

How to configure delivery and payment methods.

**1) In the first step (1/2) checkout, I can choose the form of delivery:**

- Courier shipment (paid in advance) - delivery cost 4€)
- Courier shipment (payable on delivery) - delivery cost 6€)

**2) In the last step (2/2) checkout, I can choose the payment method.**

- bank transfer
- fast online payments
- cash on delivery**

OK, just how can I do that:

When I choose the form of delivery (courier shippment payment in advance 4€) it should display only the motions of payment I pay in advance, so this:

- bank transfer
- fast online payments

When I choose the form of delivery (payable on delivery 6€) it should display only the motions of payment I pay on delivery, so only this one:

- cash on delivery

**Description issue:**

The issues is that when I select whatever shipment, all payment methods are displayed.

**For example:**

I can choose a cheaper delivery "courier shippment payment in advance 4€" and then in last step checkout I can choose the method of payment on delivery.

How to solve it ?